# A series $u_n$ converges uniformly on an interval $I$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n = 0$ uniformly on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Not sure how to start this; but I have  given any
$\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $u_n$ $\epsilon$-approximates $u$ on $I$. That is,
$$|u_n(x) − u(x)| \leq \epsilon$$
for all $x \in I$

Comment: Doesn't $1/x +1/n$ converge uniformlly on $(0,1)?$

Comment: @zhw. At first I thought "series" in the title was a typo, but the question makes more sense if the OP means "if the series $\sum u_n$ converges uniformly..."

Comment: @Bungo Right, the question needs a better statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is false if you really mean that $u_n$ is a **sequence** which converges uniformly on $I$. Such a sequence need not converge to zero. For example, put $u_n(x) = 1-1/n$ for all $x \in I$. Then $u_n \to 1$ uniformly in $I$.

Perhaps you mean that $\sum u_n$ is a **series** which converges uniformly in $I$. Then it is true that the sequence of terms $u_n$ (not necessarily the series $\sum u_n$) will converge to zero. For example, if we put $u_n(x) = 1/n^2$ for all $x \in I$, then $\sum u_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $\pi^2/6$, and the sequence $u_n(x) = 1/n^2$ converges uniformly to zero.

So, I will assume you mean that $\sum u_n$ converges uniformly on $I$ to some function $u$, and we want to show that $u_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Let $S_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}u_n(x)$ be the $N$'th partial sum of the series. Then $S_N \to u$ uniformly. This means that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $K$ such that 
$$|S_N(x) - u(x)| < \epsilon/2$$
for all $N \geq K$ and all $x \in I$. Therefore, if $N \geq K+1$, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
|u_N(x)| &=|S_N(x) - S_{N-1}(x)| \\
&= |S_N(x) - u(x) + u(x) - S_{N-1}(x)| \\
&\leq |S_N(x) - u(x)| + |S_{N-1}(x) - u(x)| \\
&< \epsilon\\
\end{aligned}$$
for all $x \in I$.